# Continuity and differentiability in one point

Tags: calculus

$F(x,y)$ and its partial derivative $\partial_yF(x,y)$ are continuous in $(x_0,y_0)$

and $F(x_0,y_0)=0$

$\partial_yF(x,y)$ is countinuous means that
$\exists \epsilon>0$ :

$\forall x \in B_r(x_0)$ 
$\forall y \in B_\delta(y_0)$

$|\partial_yF(x,y)-\partial_yF(x_0,y_0)|< \epsilon$

How can I estimate $|F(x,y_0)-F(x_0,y_0)|$ using  $\partial_yF(x,y)$ continuity?

Maybe If fix $x$ I can treat F(x,y) like a a function of the one variable y...?

Answer (score 1):

> If fix $x$ I can treat $F(x,y)$ like a a function of the one variable $y$.

Yes, you can. And you can estimate some quantities like $F(x,y_1)-F(x,y_2)$ in this way. But the partial with respect to $y$ does not help you estimate $|F(x,y_0)-F(x_0,y_0)|$. For this quantity, you can use the definition of continuity of $F$ itself.

It might help to say  what your actual goal is.